# Showing tooltips in JavaFx at specific row position in the TableView

Tags: javafx, position, tooltip, row, tableview

How can I show a tooltip for each row of a TableView?

An Example:
When I put the mouse over a specific table row it give me the details of this row's data.

Thank You

Answer (score 11):

Use a row factory, and add the tooltip to the `TableRow`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
;

public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    private final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        table.setEditable(true);

        table.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Person>() {
            private Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(person, empty);
                if (person == null) {
                    setTooltip(null);
                } else {
                    tooltip.setText(person.getFirstName()+" "+person.getLastName());
                    setTooltip(tooltip);
                }
            }
        });

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a dynamic TableRow implementation:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;

public class TooltipTableRow<T> extends TableRow<T> {

  private Function<T, String> toolTipStringFunction;

  public TooltipTableRow(Function<T, String> toolTipStringFunction) {
    this.toolTipStringFunction = toolTipStringFunction;
  }

  @Override
  protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if(item == null) {
      setTooltip(null);
    } else {
      Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip(toolTipStringFunction.apply(item));
      setTooltip(tooltip);
    }
  }
}
```

And set it up like this in the `initialize()` of your controller:

```
personTableView.setRowFactory((tableView) -> {
      return new TooltipTableRow<Person>((Person person) -> {
        return person.getFirstName()+" "+person.getLastName();
      });
});
```